# Firefox addin to "dim" a page

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I have a page opened all the time in FF, and don't want others passing by to see immediately the page.

Is there a plugin that would allow to "dim" the page, unless you over it with a mouse or set focus on window? The idea is similar to laptops screen dimming.

Comment: Lock your workstation.

Comment: Or just minimize it

Comment: Stop surfing porn at work!

Answer (score 2):

Real programmer don't use a mouse. :)

Do a ctrl-t to open a new tab, and ctrl-w to close it.

Comment: Keep another tab already open, next in line, and Ctrl+Tab to switch to it.  (I find Ctrl+Tab slightly less of a stretch that Ctrl+T.) You could even preemptively open something innocuous like Google or your local weather.  But, as above, stop surfing porn at work!

Answer (score 2):

**http://lifehacker.com/197395/porn-private-browsing-roundup**

- [Download of the Day: Stealther Firefox extension](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/download-of-the-day-stealther-firefox-extension-174752.php)
- [Safari's private (porn) browsing mode](http://www.lifehacker.com/software/mac-os-x/safaris-private-porn-browsing-mode-102146.php)
- [How to delete usage history in Windows](http://lifehacker.com/software/privacy/how-to-delete-usage-history-in-windows-174147.php)
- [Del.icio.us adds private saving feature](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/delicious-adds-private-saving-feature-161625.php)
- [Anonymous surfing for your USB thumb drive](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/anonymous-surfing-for-your-usb-thumb-drive-151494.php)
- [Stealth internet browsing with workFRIENDLY](http://www.lifehacker.com/software/top/stealth-internet-browsing-with-workfriendly-191855.php)
- [Create your own false identity](http://lifehacker.com/software/privacy/create-your-own-false-identity-181710.php)
- [Download of the Day: Ghostzilla](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/download-of-the-day-ghostzilla-179674.php)
- [Download of the Day: HideWin (Windows)](http://www.lifehacker.com/software/privacy/download-of-the-day-hidewin-windows-196378.php)

http://lifehacker.com/333026/cover-your-porn-browsing-tracks-with-hidebad

http://lifehacker.com/5065377/vanishd-hides-your-inappropriate-browsing

< 3 Lifehacker!

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, assuming you're running Windows...  Windows Key + D minimizes everything and drops to the desktop.  It makes a great "boss key."

Comment: Not really; your boss will tend to notice that you have an empty desktop. Almost better to go with `WIN`+`L` and lock.